# Owl Carousel not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel 1 and this problem shows up:

In the HTML page, there is no problem, see here:
(clients section)

Link: http://exibirhost.com.br/supplypaper/front/sobre-nos.html

But, when I've started the WordPress, this problem happened:
(clients section)

http://exibirhost.com.br/supplypaper/sobre-nos/

As you can see, the carousel broke. I have already tried to use jQuery No Conflict, and some other things, but the I can't figure out why is this bug is showing up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you are missing owl.*.css files on the second server
I've added these lines and it works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://exibirhost.com.br/supplypaper/front/css/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://exibirhost.com.br/supplypaper/front/css/owl.transitions.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://exibirhost.com.br/supplypaper/front/css/owl.carousel.css">
```

Comment: Oh boy... I can't believe....I guess i need to take a vacation lol...
Thank You very much for the help!